# calculation and changing state inside setstate in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two states result which initially set to zero and val initially set to 1.
In the multiply function, I change the states as followed.

```
multiply(){

    console.log('multiply is clicked');

    console.log('numberformed is '+this.state.numberformed);
    this.setState(()=>{
        return{


          val:this.state.val*this.state.numberformed,
          result:this.state.val,


        };

    });

   }
```

Here this.state.numberformed outputs 12 as I checked using console.
I want the result to be equal to 12 so I first changed val as it is seen in the code but the result still reads 1 which is the initial state of val and not the changed state of val.How should I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking (or why you're using a function here when you could just set the state directly). Are you asking why `this.state.val` in the `result` object isn't what you set it to in the immediately-previous line?

Comment: Yes .I want result to be equal to 12 .I changed Val equal to 12 by multiplying 1 with 12 .now I want my result state to be same as val I.e equal to 12.

Comment: @Dave Newton Can you please explain why result object isn't set to val as 12 when val is changed just above it .how can I make result equal to 12.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part of `setState` is that the name is slightly misleading. It's actually more like `scheduleStateUpdate`.

The function you supply to `setState` returns an object that React will merge with `this.state` when it updates. Before the update happens, `this.state` always refers to the **current** state. Inside the return statement, the update definitely has not happened, because the update hasn't even been scheduled yet. The return statement is what schedules the update.

It looks like this might be what you were trying to do:

```
this.setState(() => {
  const val = this.state.val * this.state.numberformed
  return {
    result: val
  }
})
```

The brackets for the return statement might be tripping you up. Yes, it looks an awful lot like the brackets for a function body, or something, where statements go. But it's actually returning a javascript *object* from the function.

The statement

```
return {
  result: val
}
```

Looks conceptually more like this:

```
return (
  { result: val }
)
```

This will add a key called `result` to `this.state`, accessible as `this.state.result`. In your code, assuming `result` was actually assigned the value you expected, two keys would have been added to state: `val` and `result`, both of which would have exactly the same value.

Since you're updating `state` with a simple calculation, you could make an even shorter version without using an intermediate variable like `val` or even a function at all:

```
this.setState({result: this.state.val * this.state.numberformed})
```

Or, more readably:

```
const { val, numberformed } = this.state
this.setState({result: val * numberformed})
```

This would set `this.state.result` to the result of the multiplication and leave every other key of `this.state` unchanged.

Comment: Hey @Phil I tried moving the val to be above return but now it give error unexpected token .I tried doing exactly that you suggest but it looks that the suggested code has a wrong syntax.

Comment: the entire line that you added const val=this.state.val*this .state.numberformed

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with sample code. Can you make it look more like your code? https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/98923/

Comment: Hey @phil I am basically trying to a make a calculator say 2*3 and my result rendred is 6 and now someone does *5  result rendered is 30 .with your code i could just render 1*10 on screen but i need to store val in result and do further calculations

Comment: Ah, I see. Then you'd need something like this https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/98925/